# There exist a hotkey to "Go to the end of the word" in Windows?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, hotkeys

There exist a hotkey to "Go to the end of the word" in Windows? or can be this created trough Autohotkey?

I know that are editors where this hotkey exist like Notepad++, VIM, etc. but what i need is a general hotkey that can be applied to any editor.

I thought that i could use the sequence Ctrl+Right, Left but if i have text with more than one space 
between words then this method doesn't work.

Comment: There isn't a hotkey by default, as you say, it depends on the editor.  You would have to define your own hotkey with a program like Autohotkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every editor is different regarding to the use of Ctrl-Right and Ctrl-Left. Sometimes they go to the end or beginning of the word, and sometimes to the next word. The editors also differ in their treatment of punctuation (.,!?). Some treat it as separate words, some as part of the word.

I am afraid there is no general method of going to the end of the word.

Comment: After a lot of search i think that you are right. As alternative I create a program in C#, to jump to the end of a word in forward and bakward directions using the PGDn and PGUp Hotkeys. Perhaps my attemps to try to make it run smooth it doesn't, basically because it need to send to much keypress and make selection and copy operations and regular expression calculations to obtain the precise location of where the cursor needs to move. As i don't have direct access to the line and as consecuence i need to rely in key simulation its never going to be smooth.